# Ghostscript and PDF font Bug

Tags: macos, pdf, fonts, terminal, ghostscript

i have a problem with ghostscript, Times New Roman and pdf.

My System:

OS: Mac 10.11.6

Ghostscript: 9.21

I want to scale my pdf with following code in terminal:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dDownsampleColorImages=true \ -dColorImageResolution=150 -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Now i have problems with the font Times New Roman.

In the Output.pdf the textline "**Unabhängige Heimatzeitung**" is broken, if you open the pdf in Safari or in Mac Quick View.

Here is the Link to the input.pdf

[input.pdf](https://cloud.rheiderland.de/index.php/s/MRPeZTwzUvgD28s)

Here is the Link to the putput.pdf

[output.pdf](https://cloud.rheiderland.de/index.php/s/AeKCqeYRCUNfyqH)

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I seem to recall we've had similar reports recently. The bug is not in Ghostscript, its the Apple PDF font rendering engine that has the bug. The PDF file is valid, as you can see if you open it in Adobe Acrobat. You should probably report this to Apple as a bug (good luck with that!). Oh, and if I'm correct, this only affects *recent* versions. Older versions of the OS are able to render the files correctly, which adds weight to it being Apple's problem.

Comment: Ok. I understand. In Windows and every other Applications on Mac like Firefox or Adobe Acrobat it looks fine. I try to get in contact with Apple.

Thank you :)

Comment: Good luck! If you can even get them to tell you what it is exactly that Quartz has a problem with we may be able to work around it.

Comment: Hi,
to convert my pdf´s to a smaller file size i use now an other solution. I have written a ExtendScript for InDesign, that place the PDF on an empty InDesign Page and export it as a pdf with custom adobe pdf settings. So i have an OCR PDF with a small file size.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that there is some problem with the PDF. Acrobat preflight reports syntax errors.

You might try a different method: produce PostScript of the PDF, then run that through GS.

Or create (or download) Quartz Filters for OS X using ColorSync Utility to reduce the size of the PDF, and apply the filter to the original PDF.

[image: PDF Preflight]

Comment: Interesting which version of Acrobat and which errors do you see ? I checked the input and outpt files with Acrobat X and see no errors from the 'PDF syntax' preflight.

Comment: I've added an image of the results. The PDF/A compliance is irrelevant, but the syntax errors are significance. 
Also, I'm not entirely convinced that your original PDF Creator is free from blame.

Comment: Could it be that the shown errors are just an attempted (and failed) validation against a PDF/A standard?

Comment: The ones marked "Syntax problem" are syntax errors, not PDF/A compliance.
"Stream dict improperly formatted" is not good in any kind of PDF.

Comment: That's not strictly true. PDF/A explicitly states certain limitations on things like line endings, which aren't the case for regular PDF. I would try using the 'PDF syntax problems' profile instead of PDF/A1-a. Its not a PDF/A file, so applying the checking against PDF/A specific issues isn't a reasonable test. The PDF syntax error profile gave me no problems with either file.

Comment: I do see the listed problems when checking PDF/A-1a compliance, but since its not a PDF/A-1a file I don't really consider those to be an issue. "Report PDF syntax issues" reports no problems.

Comment: When I try to remake the PDF I get errors or Acrobat crashes. I think it's fair to say that there is some problem with the output PDF, whatever it may be. So in terms of helping, rinsing through PostScript or using some other method to compress the PDF is the OP's best bet.

Comment: No, I do not think there is any problem with the output.pdf file. I'm prepared to believe there is, but I can't find any (it is too large and complex a file to read manually). I don't know what you mean by 'remake' the PDF file. Saving the PDF file from Acrobat works, as does optimizing, creating a reduced size PDF and rendering to image. I don't know what you are doing to see errors (because you don't say, exactly) but this file works perfectly well for me. If you are experiencing problems on a Mac, then try a different OS, we already know MacOS has a problem with this.